# how to get the value from json file using sed/aws?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, sh

I am new to sed & awk command in unix. I have output.json file that has output value of "docker ps" command:

```
$ cat output.json 
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                       COMMAND   CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
dc6f2c93c832   ankur1825/jmeter-chromewebserver:jmeterv1   "bash"    3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes             sleepy_mendeleev
```

i would like to get only CONTAINER-ID Value ie "dc62cf93c832". How do i get this via sed or awk command.

I tried below but this could have given me only Container-Id:

```
$ CONTAINER-ID=$(cat output.json | sed 's/\//_/g')
bash: CONTAINER-ID=CONTAINER: command not found
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: That isn't a JSON file. Your attempt of `sed 's/\//_/g'` makes no sense. And variable names cannot contain dashes.

Comment: A much better solution is to pass suitable parameters to `docker ps`. If you assign a name to your container with `docker run --name something` your solution will be simply `docker ps --filter name=something -q`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==2{print $1}' output.json
```

will give you the output you want but it's not clear whey you thought that input file was JSON in the first place or what you were trying to do with the sed command in your question.